# Java Arrays Index out of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I'm just starting a unit in Arrays and I was given some example code to look off of for this very basic introductory program for Arrays. Essentially all I have to do is make two arrays that ask for the temperature for that day of the week. After collecting the info it will simply spit it back out in a string like this.

The temperature on Monday was 16 degrees

The temperature on Tuesday was 18 degrees

... etc.

From what I understood from the example code I received I am doing everything correctly. But when try to run the program (in Netbeans) I get this error.

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>       at temperatures.Temperatures.main(Temperatures.java:27)
>   Java Result: 1"

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        String temp[]= new String[7];
        String day[]= new String[7];
        day[1]=("Monday");
        day[2]=("Tuesday");
        day[3]=("Wednesday");
        day[4]=("Thursday");
        day[5]=("Friday");
        day[6]=("Saturday");
        day[7]=("Sunday");
        for (int i=0; i <7; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for" + day[i]);
            temp[i]=br.readLine();
        }
        for (int i=0; i <7; i++){
        System.out.println("The high temperature on " + day[i]+ " was "+ temp[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Arrays begin at zero](http://developeronline.blogspot.com/2008/04/why-array-index-should-start-from-0.html) (<- that's a link to an article which explains why). So assigning your first value as `day[1]=("Monday");` is the issue, it should be `day[0]=("Monday");` Hope that helps

Comment: Ahh Okay, I had a feeling it would be something like a minor logical error. I re-ran the program, replacing the array numbers and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) I'm glad you figured it out! Please accept the answer you feel answered your question in the best way (click the little check mark below the voting arrows) so future comers with similar questions will know what solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays in Java start at position 0, not position 1.  So if you initialize it to a size of 7, Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6.  There is no index 7 available.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays starter in 0,

try this

```
    day[0]=("Monday");
    day[1]=("Tuesday");
    day[2]=("Wednesday");
    day[3]=("Thursday");
    day[4]=("Friday");
    day[5]=("Saturday");
    day[6]=("Sunday");
```

and should you change this loop

```
for(int i=0; i < 7; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for" + day[i]);
        temp[i]=br.readLine();
    }
```

for this

```
for(int i=0; i < day.length(); i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter the temperature for" + day[i]);
        temp[i]=br.readLine();
    }
```

I hope help you.

Comment: Watch out, this was tagged with homework. We don't want to give someone the answer explicitly, just point them in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your array starts from 1, ends from 7. If your array length is 7, the last index should be one less than tyhe array length. In your case, array sees that you have declared it for 7 elements, but inserted 8 positions. So, start array from 0, end it from 6

Answer (score 0):

If an Array is is 'N' then the boundaries of that array is 0 and "N-1". 
In your case the array Boundaries are 0 and 6. But you are tring to write value into array[7] which is not exists.